# Cleaner way to show first occurrence of letter on contacts list?

Tags: jquery, contacts, alphabetical

I have a working jQuery solution, but it seems there should be a cleaner way to only show the first alphabetical letter of a list of contact names.

I can use the database to group by the first letter, but I was hoping to just pull all the records out ordered alphabetically and just display them.  This displays them all with the first letter next to them, but I only want to display the first occurrence of each letter.

```
<div class="list" id="contacts-list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-icon">
      <span class="alphabetical-letter alphabetical-letter-A">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-primary">
      Alpha
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-icon">
      <span class="alphabetical-letter alphabetical-letter-A">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-primary">
      Alpha
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-icon">
      <span class="alphabetical-letter alphabetical-letter-A">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-primary">
      Alpha
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-icon">
      <span class="alphabetical-letter alphabetical-letter-B">B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-primary">
      Bravo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-icon">
      <span class="alphabetical-letter alphabetical-letter-B">B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-primary">
      Bravo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-icon">
      <span class="alphabetical-letter alphabetical-letter-B">B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-primary">
      Bravo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
  $(".alphabetical-letter-A:first").show();
  $(".alphabetical-letter-B:first").show();
  ...
</script>

# CSS
.alphabetical-letter {
  display: none;
}
```

It's a list of contacts sorted alphabetically, and I only want to display the first occurrence of each letter.  I tried CSS-only solutions and couldn't get those working.

Comment: Can you post enough of your HTML that we can reproduce, and work with, a slightly larger set with (anonymised) contact details)? One or two records from each of the letters `A`,`B` and `C` for example?

Comment: @DavidThomas: I updated the HTML with dummy alphabetical data for the names.  This is the structure I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Using this html structure I don't think it's possible to achieve this with CSS alone.

If you group the contacts with the same first letter into div blocks then it is possible.

```
<div class="list">

  <div class="contact-group">
    <div class="contact">
      <p>Adam</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <p>Alan</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-group">
    <div class="contact">
      <p>Barry</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <p>Brendan</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[See my example here](https://jsfiddle.net/23k3sg42/)